# Justifying "wlog" in proof of Schur's inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I was able to show the following inequality for $x,y,z\geq 0$ and $a\geq 0$:

$$x^a(x-y)(x-z) + y^a(y-x)(y-z)+z^a(z-x)(x-y) \geq 0$$

While working out the proof, I thought it would be easier to first try to prove the case when $x \leq y \leq z$. It turns out that the proof is quite simple if this is the case since we can leverage the fact that $\alpha \beta \geq0$ if and only if the signs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal (or if one one them is $0$).

It is tempting to start the proof with "without loss of generality", but it's not immediately obvious to me that there is no loss of generality, since swapping the position of $x$ and $z$ for example yields what looks like a different inequality:

$$z^a(z-y)(z-x) + y^a(y-z)(y-x)+z^a(x-z)(z-y) \geq 0$$

If we assume that the first inequality is true, then we can easily show that this inequality is also true by adding and subtracting $x$ in the right places.

**my question**

Is there some simpler way to be sure that there is no loss in generality in assuming that $x\leq y \leq z$ other than enumerating all the cases? The expression on the LHS has some symmetry, but the term involving $z^a$ seems to mess that up.

Comment: Your first inequality isn't symmetric or a Schur type inequality, unless you meant the last term to be $z^a(z-x)(z-y)$.  Hence if that isn't a typo, WLOG is not valid for this one.

Comment: Right, there is a typo in the text I was referencing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why WLOG wouldn't work.

Since $f(x,y,z,a) = f(y,z,x,a) = f(z,y,x,a) = ...$, if you showed that $f(x,y,z,a) \geq 0$ holds when $x \leq y \leq z$, then it holds for any ordering.

Original ineq:

$$x^a(x-y)(x-z) + y^a(y-z)(y-x)+z^a(z-x)(z-y) \geq 0$$

Swapping $x$ and $z$:

$$z^a(z-y)(z-x) + y^a(y-x)(y-z)+x^a(x-z)(x-y) \geq 0$$

Which is just the original inequality again.